# Rabin Miller Algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to understand Rabin Miller Algorithm, but i am confused about a little bit part. Please help in understanding it.

What i Understood:
We are calculating 's' in 2^d*s, then we are taking a random integer 'a' and calculating a^s%p, if it is equal to 1, then p is probable prime. Otherwise if for any 'r' a^(r*s)%p = -1 Then we will get 1 in next squaring, so p is prime.
In first iteration if x=1; Then we are checking it in if statement, but after 1st iteration what is the significance of if statement, I am not getting it. Please help...

Confusing Part:

```
if(mod!=p-1 && temp%2==0){
                return false;
            }
```

Origingal Miller Implementation:

```
bool Miller(long long p,int iteration){
    if(p<2){
        return false;
    }
    if(p!=2 && p%2==0){
        return false;
    }
    long long s=p-1;
    while(s%2==0){
        s/=2;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<iteration;i++){
        long long a=rand()%(p-1)+1,temp=s;
        long long mod=modulo(a,temp,p);
        while(temp!=p-1 && mod!=1 && mod!=p-1){
            mod=mulmod(mod,mod,p);
            temp *= 2;
        }
        if(mod!=p-1 && temp%2==0){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: It might be useful to note the programming language.

Comment: To note the programming language.. what's that ?

Comment: The language your code is written in. Possibly C, C++, C#, Java, etc.

Comment: nope ... nothing to deal with the programming language.

Comment: I would strongly disagree with that. On occasion, symbols mean slightly different things depending on the language. They also have different rules about syntax. For example, `long long s` might be valid in the language you're using, but I'm confident it's invalid syntax in C# and Java. The programming language at hand is *always* relevant because they all have different rules, quirks, and gotchas.

Comment: I agree with you sir, but this part is dealing with the logic only.. We are not considering language here ...

Answer (score 2):

The definition of an M-R witness is `a` such that `a**s != 1 (modulo p)` and `a**(2**r * s) != -1 (modulo p)` for all `r`. The loop bails out when `mod`, which has the value `a**(2**r * s)`, satisfies `mod == 1 (modulo p)` or `mod == -1 (modulo p)`.

If `mod == 1 (modulo p)`, then the second property of being an M-R witness is satisfied, because every value of `a**(2**r * s)` so far is not congruent to `-1 (mod p)`, and none of the future values is congruent, since they're all `1 (mod p)`. Given that the second property holds, the first property, `a**s != 1 (modulo p)`, holds if and only if the loop body executes at least once. Initially, `temp == s`, which is at most `(p - 1)/2`, and `mod != p - 1` by the second property. We have `temp % 2 == 0` if and only if the loop body executes at least once.

Comment: Mr. David, now i have just one doubt. Initially we are checking the value of mod using "long long mod=modulo(a,temp,p);" . I am assuming that here value of mod!=1 , Then if the value of mod comes out to be 1 in any iteration of the loop, then the loop terminates and the if condition is true. Why we are not handling this case... or this case can't occur ? I am asking why?

Comment: @user2379271 That case can happen, and it means that `p` is not prime. *Why* that's the case is a question for [math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Let us suppose that case occurs at 5*r, then a^((5*r)*s)%p=1. Then after squaring it every time , the value of mod will be 1, therefore at the end it will satisfy Fermat's little theorem property, according to which a^(p-1)%p==1 if p is prime.

Comment: @user2379271 If `p` is prime, you'll hit -1 (i.e., `p - 1`) first.

Comment: Mr David, I am just asking why ? Is there any logic or proof about the same ?

Comment: @user2379271 The integers modulo p are an integral domain (a field, actually). That means that the equation x^2 = 1 (mod p), which is equivalent to (x - 1) * (x + 1) = 0 (mod p), has two solutions: x = 1, and x = -1. If x <> 1 but x^2 = 1, then x = -1.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33458/discussion-between-user2379271-and-david-eisenstat)

Comment: what is x<>1 ?
Secondly, if it means x< 1 , then what you are saying is correct but we can't be sure becuase modulo(%) is playing that role